# como cambiar la imagen de fondo de pagina html con una variable definida en php

Tags: php, html

Quiero hacer que mi sistema use la tabla Parametros para mostrar la imagen de fondo del sistema.
Esto debe ir en la parte HTML al final de cada página PHP de mi sistema.
Usando la información disponible, he utilizado este código como pie de página:

```
<?php  //lee la tabla Parametros y define la variable $urlimage (entre otras cosas)
```

print $urlimage;   // si me muestra la url correcta donde está la imagen a mostrar
?>
Muestra titulo pagina
 //esta es la original que si funciona, pero la quiero reemplazar con la variable $urlimage que contiene la dirección definida en la tabla Parametros que previamente leo y si está definida y cargada con el url correcto:

```
<body style="background-image: <?PHP echo (isset($urlimage) && $urlimage == true)? $urlimage : '../imagenes/portada.png'; ?>">  

</body>
</html>
```

Ese código con la parte PHP insertada lo he tomado de la respuesta "Cambiar color de fondo" y la he adaptado, pero no me funciona para hacer el mostrar la imagen de la variable $urlimage
¿Cómo sería la forma correcta de lograrlo?
muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolví...  esta es la forma correcta:

```
<body style="background-image: url(<?php echo (isset($urlimage) && $urlimage == true)? $urlimage : $urlimage; ?>)">
```

espero les sea de utilidad.
gracias de todas maneras.

Comment: No olvides [edit] tu respuesta para explicar el código. Lee [answer]. Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.